# Is there a simpler way to code the following C# sentence

Tags: c#

Is there a simpler or alternate way to code the following C# sentence?

```
if (iValue >= 4 && iValue <= 10) {... other code ...}
```

Do I need to repeat the `iValue` twice?

I have seen a structure similar to `_ = ...some code...`  but I am not familiar with that leading underscore?

Comment: I don't know why people are voting to close the question as duplicate.. None of the specified duplicates has the up-to-date answer, which is `if (iValue is >= 4 and <= 10)`

Comment: @Youssef13 then add an answer to one of the existing questions? It looks like the answer is there though.

Comment: @Youssef13 the first one, second floor.

Comment: Please re-state your comment as an ANSWER and I will post your answer as the answer....thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With C#9 you can use:

```
if(iValue is >= 4 and <= 10)
{
    Console.WriteLine("in range");
}
```

Comment: I was wondering about the performance (micro-optimizations, I know) but this gives literally the same IL as `if(iValue >= 4 && iValue <= 10)`. So that's cool!